# COBOL accurate LENGTH OF (XML-TEXT) when ampersands escaped?

Tags: xml-parsing, cobol

I'm using the intrinsic function XML-PARSE with XML that looks like this:

```
<MSGBODYTXT>
 <LN>One &amp; two</LN>
</MSGBODYTXT>
```

By my count, the following string is 13 bytes long.

```
  "One &amp; two"
```

But when I take     $ 
LENGTH OF(XML-TEXT)     $
I get only 9 bytes.

What can I do to get the correct, 13-byte length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that XML PARSE translates `&amp;` into the character it represents, an ampersand. If
you look at the `CONTENT-CHARACTERS` associated with the `<LN>` tag you will see: `One & two` which
is 9 characters long, just as the `LENGTH OF` operator on `XML-TEXT` says it is.

Note that if you were to use XML GENERATE on data item `LN` having the value `One & two`
it will generate as `<LN>One &amp; two</LN>` which is a symetrical operation.